# AngularJS display one json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I receive from my rest api news with the specified id. When I display all news I used `ng-repeat` and works fine but when I want display one object this method is not working.

My `.when` code:

```
.when('/displaynews/:id',{
    templateUrl: 'views/display.html',
    controller: 'NewsDisplayController',
    constollerAs: 'displaydash'
})
```

and the `controller`:

```
.controller('NewsDisplayController',
    function($routeParams, NewsModel){

      var displaydash = this;
      var newsId = $routeParams.id;
      path = 'getNewsById/'+newsId;

      function getNewsById() {
          NewsModel.getNewsById().then(function (result){
              displaydash.news = result.data;
              console.log(displaydash.news);
          })
      }

      getNewsById();
})
```

Result from console.log:

```
Object { id="56f1ba6b275c8aa5bf4895d8",  title="Tytul",  text="Text",  more...}
```

How can I display this in my html template?

I try to display in html file in this way:

```
<p>{{news.title}}</p>
<p>{{news.text}}</p>
```

But it's not working

Comment: what have you tried?  Looks like it will just work to bind to `news`, correct?

Comment: Do you want to show the JSON as a JSON string, or show the content out of it?

Comment: `But it's not working` how? do you get an error?

Comment: No, no errors. Just blank page.

Comment: Have you tried to bind *anything* to the template.  Try a hard coded property of `displaydash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for :

```
angular.toJson(JSONObj);
```

So, here you can go for:
in Controller:

```
displaydash.news = result.data;
$scope.news      = angular.toJson(displaydash.news);
```

in HTML:

```
<p>{{news}}</p>
```

The issue in your question is simple, you are trying to access news object which you have not defined, try creating a scope variable for it, you will be easily able to access it:

```
 $scope.displaydash.news = result.data;

<p>{{displaydash.news.title}}</p>
<p>{{displaydash.news.text}}</p>
```

Refer: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson

Comment: the OP is attempting to use the *controller as* method of binding.  So, no `$scope` required.

Comment: 'OP'? What's that?

Comment: Original Post.  You will come across abbreviation here on SO a lot.

Comment: @Davin Tryon Thanks, but in angular you require a $scope variable to be able to bind the value to html, it is required by the way.

Comment: When id put `<p>{{news}}</p>` I get `{"id":"56f149110706d23db6542453","title":"Tytul","text":"Tresc","data":"Data","author":"Autor"}` but when I put `<p>{{displaydash.news.title}}</p>` I get nothing

Comment: And error: Error: `$scope.displaydash is undefined`

Comment: `but in angular you require a $scope variable to be able to bind the value `, that is just **incorrect**.  In fact even the documented example on the angular docs now uses *controller as* syntax: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Comment: You might find this interesting as well: https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: @DavinTryon Thanks Buddy, Didn't know that... It's really cool without using the $scope variable, upvoted... :)

Answer (score 1):

If `result.data` is an object, enclose it with square brackets and set as `news`, otherwise use it directly.

```
 displaydash.news = typeof(result.data) == "object"?[result.data]: result.data;
```

Comment: why turn it into an array?

Comment: lukassz is using ng-repeat and the code works fine when there are multiple objects. So converting the single object to an array should work.

Comment: @Gilsha, good point, but the api will be returning an array structure right? Even if we have just one object?

Comment: Did you see the `console.log` output in the question? It shows an object and not an array.So assuming `getNewsById` API returns a single object. lukassz may be using some other API for loading multiple news items.

Comment: Right... Thanks @Gilsha